# How can I scrape Json data from Highcharts (stats.twitchapps.com)

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I'm doing a school project where i need hard data on twitch viewership. I found a great site, stats.twitchapps.com that has all of these data in charts.

However, I need the data in excel format to do statistical analysis on it for my class.

I have some background in C# programmin. I've been trying to scrape the data using C# and Json.Net), but i'm not having much luck....

Here is the php file that contains the chart: view-source:http://stats.twitchapps.com/categories.php

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how i might go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The graph source data can be found [here](https://stats.twitchapps.com/api/categorydata.php?callback=?). It's an array of arrays with [JStimestamp, viewers]. I'm sure you'll find a way to get this into excel (e.g. convert the array to lines and then to a CSV format which can be imported into excel), although I'm not really sure why anyone would want to work with this amount of data in excel... Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning I recommend you to visit [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json) website. In the excel you can export data to csv, which can be loaded by $.get() method in jquery. Next step is parse your data to correct format (data array in series object) and return a chart.